# Removing punctuation from txt file in Linux terminal using 'tr' and 'awk' commands

Tags: linux, awk, terminal, command

I'm currently taking a crash course in the basics of the Linux terminal and one of the tasks is to replace punctuation in a text file using 'awk' and 'tr' commands. I have tried searching around for solutions but nothing is working for me, any help?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The quick tip is `tr -d '[:punct:]'` but your question is very vague: replace with what?

Answer (score 10):

Using `tr` (as Glenn Jackman has already pointed out):

```
cat TEXTFILE | tr -d '[:punct:]' > OUTFILE
```

Using `awk` (tested with `gawk` and `mawk`):

```
cat TEXTFILE | awk '{ gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $0) } 1;' > OUTFILE
```

You can also omit `cat` with AWK:

```
awk '{ gsub(/[[:punct:]]/, "", $0) } 1;' TEXTFILE > OUTFILE
```

Note: TEXTFILE and OUTFILE must be different.

Comment: Be advised, you never can have `OUTFILE` to be equal to `TEXTFILE`. Have a look at [Bash Pitfalls 13](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cat_file_.7C_sed_s.2Ffoo.2Fbar.2F_.3E_file)

Comment: @kvantour, yeah, I guess even with `cat` there is no guarantee that `cat` will finish reading before `awk` wants to write to it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

tr --help, the -d deletes
tr -d [:punct:] < inputfile > outputfile